# Kubernetes not regenerating SSL Certificate

Tags: ssl-certificate, kubernetes, lets-encrypt, ingress

I have tried and tried many different things, and I'm unable to land into a solution. The certificate was issued once using letsencrypt, but was never refreshed. Could you people give me a hint on what I'm doing wrong? This is my current setup:

```
    apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1alpha2
    kind: ClusterIssuer
    metadata:
      name: letsencrypt-prod
    spec:
      acme:
        server: https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
        email: <mi email>
        privateKeySecretRef:
          name: letsencrypt-prod
        solvers:
          - http01:
              ingress:
                class: nginx
    ---
    apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
    kind: Ingress
    metadata:
      name: external-ingress
      annotations:
        kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
        kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
        certmanager.k8s.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-prod
        ingress.kubernetes.io/secure-backends: "true"
    spec:
      tls:
        - hosts:
            - example.com
          secretName: example-tls
      rules:
        - host: example.com
          http:
            paths:
              - path: /
                backend:
                  serviceName: web-service
                  servicePort: 4000
    ---
    apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1alpha2
    kind: Certificate
    metadata:
      name: example-tls
    spec:
      secretName: example-tls
      issuerRef:
        name: letsencrypt-prod
      commonName: example.com
      dnsNames:
        - www.example.com
        - example.com
    ---
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Service
    metadata:
      name: web-service
    spec:
      type: ClusterIP
      selector:
        pod: web
      ports:
        - protocol: TCP
          port: 4000
          targetPort: 8000
```

[EDIT] Here are the latest logs which include the output of 2 or 3 changes I made:

```
W0226 19:21:59.418601       1 reflector.go:299] external/io_k8s_client_go/tools/cache/reflector.go:96: watch of *v1alpha2.Certificate ended with: too old resource version: 20102319 (57035298)
W0226 19:22:00.706904       1 reflector.go:299] external/io_k8s_client_go/tools/cache/reflector.go:96: watch of *v1alpha2.Challenge ended with: too old resource version: 20102318 (57035302)
W0226 19:22:02.208128       1 reflector.go:299] external/io_k8s_client_go/tools/cache/reflector.go:96: watch of *v1alpha2.ClusterIssuer ended with: too old resource version: 20102319 (57035310)
W0226 19:22:03.492014       1 reflector.go:299] external/io_k8s_client_go/tools/cache/reflector.go:96: watch of *v1alpha2.Issuer ended with: too old resource version: 20102318 (57035315)
I0226 19:28:32.827986       1 controller.go:129] cert-manager/controller/clusterissuers "level"=0 "msg"="syncing item" "key"="letsencrypt-prod" 
I0226 19:28:32.834873       1 setup.go:86] cert-manager/controller/clusterissuers "level"=0 "msg"="generating acme account private key" "related_resource_kind"="Secret" "related_resource_name"="letsencrypt-prod-key" "related_resource_namespace"="cert-manager" "resource_kind"="ClusterIssuer" "resource_name"="letsencrypt-prod" "resource_namespace"="" 
I0226 19:28:33.004479       1 controller.go:129] cert-manager/controller/webhook-bootstrap "level"=0 "msg"="syncing item" "key"="cert-manager/letsencrypt-prod-key" 
I0226 19:28:33.004517       1 controller.go:135] cert-manager/controller/webhook-bootstrap "level"=0 "msg"="finished processing work item" "key"="cert-manager/letsencrypt-prod-key" 
I0226 19:28:33.005861       1 setup.go:167] cert-manager/controller/clusterissuers "level"=0 "msg"="ACME server URL host and ACME private key registration host differ. Re-checking ACME account registration" "related_resource_kind"="Secret" "related_resource_name"="letsencrypt-prod-key" "related_resource_namespace"="cert-manager" "resource_kind"="ClusterIssuer" "resource_name"="letsencrypt-prod" "resource_namespace"="" 
I0226 19:28:33.005988       1 logger.go:88] Calling GetAccount
I0226 19:28:33.406134       1 logger.go:83] Calling CreateAccount
I0226 19:28:33.500282       1 setup.go:229] cert-manager/controller/clusterissuers "level"=0 "msg"="verified existing registration with ACME server" "related_resource_kind"="Secret" "related_resource_name"="letsencrypt-prod-key" "related_resource_namespace"="cert-manager" "resource_kind"="ClusterIssuer" "resource_name"="letsencrypt-prod" "resource_namespace"="" 
I0226 19:28:33.500466       1 conditions.go:92] Setting lastTransitionTime for Issuer "letsencrypt-prod" condition "Ready" to 2020-02-26 19:28:33.500447206 +0000 UTC m=+6081889.996740166
I0226 19:28:33.510355       1 controller.go:135] cert-manager/controller/clusterissuers "level"=0 "msg"="finished processing work item" "key"="letsencrypt-prod" 
I0226 19:28:33.510519       1 controller.go:129] cert-manager/controller/clusterissuers "level"=0 "msg"="syncing item" "key"="letsencrypt-prod" 
I0226 19:28:33.510996       1 setup.go:161] cert-manager/controller/clusterissuers "level"=0 "msg"="skipping re-verifying ACME account as cached registration details look sufficient" "related_resource_kind"="Secret" "related_resource_name"="letsencrypt-prod-key" "related_resource_namespace"="cert-manager" "resource_kind"="ClusterIssuer" "resource_name"="letsencrypt-prod" "resource_namespace"="" 
I0226 19:28:33.512002       1 controller.go:135] cert-manager/controller/clusterissuers "level"=0 "msg"="finished processing work item" "key"="letsencrypt-prod" 
I0226 19:28:33.689098       1 controller.go:129] cert-manager/controller/certificates "level"=0 "msg"="syncing item" "key"="default/example-tls" 
E0226 19:28:34.305985       1 pki.go:128] cert-manager/controller/certificates "msg"="error decoding x509 certificate" "error"="error decoding cert PEM block" "related_resource_kind"="Secret" "related_resource_name"="example-tls" "related_resource_namespace"="default" "resource_kind"="Certificate" "resource_name"="example-tls" "resource_namespace"="default" "secret_key"="tls.crt" 
I0226 19:28:34.306020       1 conditions.go:155] Setting lastTransitionTime for Certificate "example-tls" condition "Ready" to 2020-02-26 19:28:34.306016164 +0000 UTC m=+6081890.802309099
I0226 19:28:34.314767       1 controller.go:135] cert-manager/controller/certificates "level"=0 "msg"="finished processing work item" "key"="default/example-tls" 
I0226 19:28:34.314803       1 controller.go:129] cert-manager/controller/certificates "level"=0 "msg"="syncing item" "key"="default/example-tls" 
I0226 19:28:34.315105       1 sync.go:361] cert-manager/controller/certificates "level"=0 "msg"="no existing CertificateRequest resource exists, creating new request..." "related_resource_kind"="Secret" "related_resource_name"="example-tls" "related_resource_namespace"="default" "resource_kind"="Certificate" "resource_name"="example-tls" "resource_namespace"="default" 
I0226 19:28:34.337317       1 sync.go:373] cert-manager/controller/certificates "level"=0 "msg"="created certificate request" "related_resource_kind"="Secret" "related_resource_name"="example-tls" "related_resource_namespace"="default" "resource_kind"="Certificate" "resource_name"="example-tls" "resource_namespace"="default" "request_name"="example-tls-3355383384"
E0226 19:28:34.338431       1 pki.go:128] cert-manager/controller/certificates "msg"="error decoding x509 certificate" "error"="error decoding cert PEM block" "related_resource_kind"="Secret" "related_resource_name"="example-tls" "related_resource_namespace"="default" "resource_kind"="Certificate" "resource_name"="example-tls" "resource_namespace"="default" "secret_key"="tls.crt" 
I0226 19:28:34.338617       1 conditions.go:155] Setting lastTransitionTime for Certificate "example-tls" condition "Ready" to 2020-02-26 19:28:34.33861082 +0000 UTC m=+6081890.834903757
I0226 19:28:34.339270       1 controller.go:129] cert-manager/controller/certificaterequests-issuer-vault "level"=0 "msg"="syncing item" "key"="default/example-tls-3355383384" 
I0226 19:28:34.339369       1 controller.go:129] cert-manager/controller/certificaterequests-issuer-ca "level"=0 "msg"="syncing item" "key"="default/example-tls-3355383384" 
I0226 19:28:34.339604       1 conditions.go:200] Setting lastTransitionTime for CertificateRequest "example-tls-3355383384" condition "Ready" to 2020-02-26 19:28:34.339596714 +0000 UTC m=+6081890.835889670
I0226 19:28:34.339905       1 controller.go:129] cert-manager/controller/certificaterequests-issuer-selfsigned "level"=0 "msg"="syncing item" "key"="default/example-tls-3355383384" 
I0226 19:28:34.340089       1 conditions.go:200] Setting lastTransitionTime for CertificateRequest "example-tls-3355383384" condition "Ready" to 2020-02-26 19:28:34.340084454 +0000 UTC m=+6081890.836377378
I0226 19:28:34.340122       1 controller.go:129] cert-manager/controller/certificaterequests-issuer-venafi "level"=0 "msg"="syncing item" "key"="default/example-tls-3355383384" 
I0226 19:28:34.340485       1 conditions.go:200] Setting lastTransitionTime for CertificateRequest "example-tls-3355383384" condition "Ready" to 2020-02-26 19:28:34.340480478 +0000 UTC m=+6081890.836773397
I0226 19:28:34.340152       1 controller.go:129] cert-manager/controller/certificaterequests-issuer-acme "level"=0 "msg"="syncing item" "key"="default/example-tls-3355383384" 
I0226 19:28:34.341293       1 conditions.go:200] Setting lastTransitionTime for CertificateRequest "example-tls-3355383384" condition "Ready" to 2020-02-26 19:28:34.341288083 +0000 UTC m=+6081890.837581015
I0226 19:28:34.339630       1 conditions.go:200] Setting lastTransitionTime for CertificateRequest "example-tls-3355383384" condition "Ready" to 2020-02-26 19:28:34.339591879 +0000 UTC m=+6081890.835884796
E0226 19:28:34.361771       1 controller.go:131] cert-manager/controller/certificaterequests-issuer-venafi "msg"="re-queuing item  due to error processing" "error"="Operation cannot be fulfilled on certificaterequests.cert-manager.io \"example-tls-3355383384\": the object has been modified; please apply your changes to the latest version and try again" "key"="default/example-tls-3355383384" 
I0226 19:28:34.361829       1 controller.go:129] cert-manager/controller/certificaterequests-issuer-venafi "level"=0 "msg"="syncing item" "key"="default/example-tls-3355383384" 
I0226 19:28:34.362171       1 controller.go:135] cert-manager/controller/certificaterequests-issuer-venafi "level"=0 "msg"="finished processing work item" "key"="default/example-tls-3355383384" 
E0226 19:28:34.362545       1 controller.go:131] cert-manager/controller/certificaterequests-issuer-selfsigned "msg"="re-queuing item  due to error processing" "error"="Operation cannot be fulfilled on certificaterequests.cert-manager.io \"example-tls-3355383384\": the object has been modified; please apply your changes to the latest version and try again" "key"="default/example-tls-3355383384" 
I0226 19:28:34.362587       1 controller.go:129] cert-manager/controller/certificaterequests-issuer-selfsigned "level"=0 "msg"="syncing item" "key"="default/example-tls-3355383384" 
I0226 19:28:34.362744       1 controller.go:135] cert-manager/controller/certificaterequests-issuer-selfsigned "level"=0 "msg"="finished processing work item" "key"="default/example-tls-3355383384" 
E0226 19:28:34.363722       1 controller.go:131] cert-manager/controller/certificates "msg"="re-queuing item  due to error processing" "error"="Operation cannot be fulfilled on certificates.cert-manager.io \"example-tls\": the object has been modified; please apply your changes to the latest version and try again" "key"="default/example-tls" 
I0226 19:28:34.363765       1 controller.go:129] cert-manager/controller/certificates "level"=0 "msg"="syncing item" "key"="default/example-tls" 
I0226 19:28:34.364148       1 sync.go:379] cert-manager/controller/certificates "level"=0 "msg"="validating existing CSR data" "related_resource_kind"="CertificateRequest" "related_resource_name"="example-tls-3355383384" "related_resource_namespace"="default" "resource_kind"="Certificate" "resource_name"="example-tls" "resource_namespace"="default" 
I0226 19:28:34.364427       1 sync.go:479] cert-manager/controller/certificates "level"=0 "msg"="CertificateRequest is not in a final state, waiting until CertificateRequest is complete" "related_resource_kind"="CertificateRequest" "related_resource_name"="example-tls-3355383384" "related_resource_namespace"="default" "resource_kind"="Certificate" "resource_name"="example-tls" "resource_namespace"="default" "state"="Pending"
E0226 19:28:34.364645       1 pki.go:128] cert-manager/controller/certificates "msg"="error decoding x509 certificate" "error"="error decoding cert PEM block" "related_resource_kind"="Secret" "related_resource_name"="example-tls" "related_resource_namespace"="default" "resource_kind"="Certificate" "resource_name"="example-tls" "resource_namespace"="default" "secret_key"="tls.crt" 
E0226 19:28:34.365169       1 controller.go:131] cert-manager/controller/certificaterequests-issuer-vault "msg"="re-queuing item  due to error processing" "error"="Operation cannot be fulfilled on certificaterequests.cert-manager.io \"example-tls-3355383384\": the object has been modified; please apply your changes to the latest version and try again" "key"="default/example-tls-3355383384" 
I0226 19:28:34.365210       1 controller.go:129] cert-manager/controller/certificaterequests-issuer-vault "level"=0 "msg"="syncing item" "key"="default/example-tls-3355383384" 
I0226 19:28:34.365402       1 controller.go:135] cert-manager/controller/certificaterequests-issuer-vault "level"=0 "msg"="finished processing work item" "key"="default/example-tls-3355383384" 
I0226 19:28:34.365624       1 controller.go:135] cert-manager/controller/certificaterequests-issuer-ca "level"=0 "msg"="finished processing work item" "key"="default/example-tls-3355383384" 
I0226 19:28:34.365663       1 controller.go:129] cert-manager/controller/certificaterequests-issuer-ca "level"=0 "msg"="syncing item" "key"="default/example-tls-3355383384" 
E0226 19:28:34.366005       1 controller.go:131] cert-manager/controller/certificaterequests-issuer-acme "msg"="re-queuing item  due to error processing" "error"="Operation cannot be fulfilled on certificaterequests.cert-manager.io \"example-tls-3355383384\": the object has been modified; please apply your changes to the latest version and try again" "key"="default/example-tls-3355383384" 
I0226 19:28:34.366156       1 controller.go:135] cert-manager/controller/certificaterequests-issuer-ca "level"=0 "msg"="finished processing work item" "key"="default/example-tls-3355383384" 
I0226 19:28:34.366217       1 controller.go:129] cert-manager/controller/certificaterequests-issuer-acme "level"=0 "msg"="syncing item" "key"="default/example-tls-3355383384" 
I0226 19:28:34.366416       1 controller.go:135] cert-manager/controller/certificaterequests-issuer-acme "level"=0 "msg"="finished processing work item" "key"="default/example-tls-3355383384" 
I0226 19:28:34.380457       1 controller.go:135] cert-manager/controller/certificates "level"=0 "msg"="finished processing work item" "key"="default/example-tls" 
I0226 19:28:34.380509       1 controller.go:129] cert-manager/controller/certificates "level"=0 "msg"="syncing item" "key"="default/example-tls" 
I0226 19:28:34.380988       1 sync.go:379] cert-manager/controller/certificates "level"=0 "msg"="validating existing CSR data" "related_resource_kind"="CertificateRequest" "related_resource_name"="example-tls-3355383384" "related_resource_namespace"="default" "resource_kind"="Certificate" "resource_name"="example-tls" "resource_namespace"="default" 
I0226 19:28:34.381222       1 sync.go:479] cert-manager/controller/certificates "level"=0 "msg"="CertificateRequest is not in a final state, waiting until CertificateRequest is complete" "related_resource_kind"="CertificateRequest" "related_resource_name"="example-tls-3355383384" "related_resource_namespace"="default" "resource_kind"="Certificate" "resource_name"="example-tls" "resource_namespace"="default" "state"="Pending"
E0226 19:28:34.381431       1 pki.go:128] cert-manager/controller/certificates "msg"="error decoding x509 certificate" "error"="error decoding cert PEM block" "related_resource_kind"="Secret" "related_resource_name"="example-tls" "related_resource_namespace"="default" "resource_kind"="Certificate" "resource_name"="example-tls" "resource_namespace"="default" "secret_key"="tls.crt" 
I0226 19:28:34.381679       1 controller.go:135] cert-manager/controller/certificates "level"=0 "msg"="finished processing work item" "key"="default/example-tls" 
I0226 19:28:38.003631       1 controller.go:129] cert-manager/controller/clusterissuers "level"=0 "msg"="syncing item" "key"="letsencrypt-prod" 
I0226 19:28:38.003935       1 setup.go:161] cert-manager/controller/clusterissuers "level"=0 "msg"="skipping re-verifying ACME account as cached registration details look sufficient" "related_resource_kind"="Secret" "related_resource_name"="letsencrypt-prod-key" "related_resource_namespace"="cert-manager" "resource_kind"="ClusterIssuer" "resource_name"="letsencrypt-prod" "resource_namespace"="" 
I0226 19:28:38.004082       1 controller.go:135] cert-manager/controller/clusterissuers "level"=0 "msg"="finished processing work item" "key"="letsencrypt-prod" 
I0226 19:28:39.362069       1 controller.go:129] cert-manager/controller/certificaterequests-issuer-venafi "level"=0 "msg"="syncing item" "key"="default/example-tls-3355383384" 
I0226 19:28:39.362358       1 controller.go:135] cert-manager/controller/certificaterequests-issuer-venafi "level"=0 "msg"="finished processing work item" "key"="default/example-tls-3355383384" 
I0226 19:28:39.362732       1 controller.go:129] cert-manager/controller/certificaterequests-issuer-selfsigned "level"=0 "msg"="syncing item" "key"="default/example-tls-3355383384" 
I0226 19:28:39.362895       1 controller.go:135] cert-manager/controller/certificaterequests-issuer-selfsigned "level"=0 "msg"="finished processing work item" "key"="default/example-tls-3355383384" 
I0226 19:28:39.363917       1 controller.go:129] cert-manager/controller/certificates "level"=0 "msg"="syncing item" "key"="default/example-tls" 
I0226 19:28:39.364256       1 sync.go:379] cert-manager/controller/certificates "level"=0 "msg"="validating existing CSR data" "related_resource_kind"="CertificateRequest" "related_resource_name"="example-tls-3355383384" "related_resource_namespace"="default" "resource_kind"="Certificate" "resource_name"="example-tls" "resource_namespace"="default" 
I0226 19:28:39.364992       1 sync.go:479] cert-manager/controller/certificates "level"=0 "msg"="CertificateRequest is not in a final state, waiting until CertificateRequest is complete" "related_resource_kind"="CertificateRequest" "related_resource_name"="example-tls-3355383384" "related_resource_namespace"="default" "resource_kind"="Certificate" "resource_name"="example-tls" "resource_namespace"="default" "state"="Pending"
E0226 19:28:39.365241       1 pki.go:128] cert-manager/controller/certificates "msg"="error decoding x509 certificate" "error"="error decoding cert PEM block" "related_resource_kind"="Secret" "related_resource_name"="example-tls" "related_resource_namespace"="default" "resource_kind"="Certificate" "resource_name"="example-tls" "resource_namespace"="default" "secret_key"="tls.crt" 
I0226 19:28:39.365404       1 controller.go:135] cert-manager/controller/certificates "level"=0 "msg"="finished processing work item" "key"="default/example-tls" 
I0226 19:28:39.365457       1 controller.go:129] cert-manager/controller/certificaterequests-issuer-vault "level"=0 "msg"="syncing item" "key"="default/example-tls-3355383384" 
I0226 19:28:39.365595       1 controller.go:135] cert-manager/controller/certificaterequests-issuer-vault "level"=0 "msg"="finished processing work item" "key"="default/example-tls-3355383384" 
I0226 19:28:39.366141       1 controller.go:129] cert-manager/controller/certificaterequests-issuer-acme "level"=0 "msg"="syncing item" "key"="default/example-tls-3355383384" 
I0226 19:28:39.366255       1 controller.go:135] cert-manager/controller/certificaterequests-issuer-acme "level"=0 "msg"="finished processing work item" "key"="default/example-tls-3355383384" 
I0226 21:06:24.117890       1 controller.go:129] cert-manager/controller/ingress-shim "level"=0 "msg"="syncing item" "key"="default/external-ingress" 
E0226 21:06:24.118633       1 sync.go:57] cert-manager/controller/ingress-shim "msg"="failed to determine issuer to be used for ingress resource" "error"="failed to determine issuer name to be used for ingress resource" "resource_kind"="Ingress" "resource_name"="external-ingress" "resource_namespace"="default" 
I0226 21:06:24.118876       1 controller.go:135] cert-manager/controller/ingress-shim "level"=0 "msg"="finished processing work item" "key"="default/external-ingress" 
I0226 21:15:27.660117       1 controller.go:129] cert-manager/controller/clusterissuers "level"=0 "msg"="syncing item" "key"="letsencrypt-prod" 
I0226 21:15:27.660248       1 setup.go:86] cert-manager/controller/clusterissuers "level"=0 "msg"="generating acme account private key" "related_resource_kind"="Secret" "related_resource_name"="letsencrypt-prod" "related_resource_namespace"="cert-manager" "resource_kind"="ClusterIssuer" "resource_name"="letsencrypt-prod" "resource_namespace"="" 
I0226 21:15:28.153028       1 setup.go:167] cert-manager/controller/clusterissuers "level"=0 "msg"="ACME server URL host and ACME private key registration host differ. Re-checking ACME account registration" "related_resource_kind"="Secret" "related_resource_name"="letsencrypt-prod" "related_resource_namespace"="cert-manager" "resource_kind"="ClusterIssuer" "resource_name"="letsencrypt-prod" "resource_namespace"="" 
I0226 21:15:28.153059       1 logger.go:88] Calling GetAccount
I0226 21:15:28.153331       1 controller.go:129] cert-manager/controller/webhook-bootstrap "level"=0 "msg"="syncing item" "key"="cert-manager/letsencrypt-prod" 
I0226 21:15:28.153497       1 controller.go:135] cert-manager/controller/webhook-bootstrap "level"=0 "msg"="finished processing work item" "key"="cert-manager/letsencrypt-prod" 
I0226 21:15:28.413415       1 logger.go:83] Calling CreateAccount
I0226 21:15:28.469758       1 setup.go:229] cert-manager/controller/clusterissuers "level"=0 "msg"="verified existing registration with ACME server" "related_resource_kind"="Secret" "related_resource_name"="letsencrypt-prod" "related_resource_namespace"="cert-manager" "resource_kind"="ClusterIssuer" "resource_name"="letsencrypt-prod" "resource_namespace"="" 
I0226 21:15:28.475847       1 controller.go:135] cert-manager/controller/clusterissuers "level"=0 "msg"="finished processing work item" "key"="letsencrypt-prod" 
I0226 21:15:28.476076       1 controller.go:129] cert-manager/controller/clusterissuers "level"=0 "msg"="syncing item" "key"="letsencrypt-prod" 
I0226 21:15:28.476426       1 setup.go:161] cert-manager/controller/clusterissuers "level"=0 "msg"="skipping re-verifying ACME account as cached registration details look sufficient" "related_resource_kind"="Secret" "related_resource_name"="letsencrypt-prod" "related_resource_namespace"="cert-manager" "resource_kind"="ClusterIssuer" "resource_name"="letsencrypt-prod" "resource_namespace"="" 
I0226 21:15:28.476584       1 controller.go:135] cert-manager/controller/clusterissuers "level"=0 "msg"="finished processing work item" "key"="letsencrypt-prod" 
I0226 21:15:33.153209       1 controller.go:129] cert-manager/controller/clusterissuers "level"=0 "msg"="syncing item" "key"="letsencrypt-prod" 
I0226 21:15:33.153499       1 setup.go:161] cert-manager/controller/clusterissuers "level"=0 "msg"="skipping re-verifying ACME account as cached registration details look sufficient" "related_resource_kind"="Secret" "related_resource_name"="letsencrypt-prod" "related_resource_namespace"="cert-manager" "resource_kind"="ClusterIssuer" "resource_name"="letsencrypt-prod" "resource_namespace"="" 
I0226 21:15:33.153537       1 controller.go:135] cert-manager/controller/clusterissuers "level"=0 "msg"="finished processing work item" "key"="letsencrypt-prod"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears you are running 4 cert issuers in your cluster, and they all believe they own the certificate, thus stepping on each other's toes, as they try to modify the same certificate resource at the same second (within even the same 100ths of a second):

```
E0226 19:28:34.361771       1 controller.go:131] cert-manager/controller/certificaterequests-issuer-venafi "msg"="re-queuing item  due to error processing" "error"="Operation cannot be fulfilled on certificaterequests.cert-manager.io \"example-tls-3355383384\": the object has been modified; please apply your changes to the latest version and try again" "key"="default/example-tls-3355383384" 
E0226 19:28:34.362545       1 controller.go:131] cert-manager/controller/certificaterequests-issuer-selfsigned "msg"="re-queuing item  due to error processing" "error"="Operation cannot be fulfilled on certificaterequests.cert-manager.io \"example-tls-3355383384\": the object has been modified; please apply your changes to the latest version and try again" "key"="default/example-tls-3355383384" 
E0226 19:28:34.365169       1 controller.go:131] cert-manager/controller/certificaterequests-issuer-vault "msg"="re-queuing item  due to error processing" "error"="Operation cannot be fulfilled on certificaterequests.cert-manager.io \"example-tls-3355383384\": the object has been modified; please apply your changes to the latest version and try again" "key"="default/example-tls-3355383384" 
E0226 19:28:34.366005       1 controller.go:131] cert-manager/controller/certificaterequests-issuer-acme "msg"="re-queuing item  due to error processing" "error"="Operation cannot be fulfilled on certificaterequests.cert-manager.io \"example-tls-3355383384\": the object has been modified; please apply your changes to the latest version and try again" "key"="default/example-tls-3355383384"
```

It appears from the shim error:

```
E0226 21:06:24.118633       1 sync.go:57] cert-manager/controller/ingress-shim "msg"="failed to determine issuer to be used for ingress resource" "error"="failed to determine issuer name to be used for ingress resource" "resource_kind"="Ingress" "resource_name"="external-ingress" "resource_namespace"="default"
```

that you are using the [wrong annotation namespace](https://cert-manager.io/docs/usage/ingress/#supported-annotations), since the modern one expects `cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer:` and not the `k8s.io` one